# How can i use TCP/IP communication routine in a different thread for continuous operation

Tags: python, tkinter, tcp, raspberry-pi, interrupt-handling

I am working in a project where I interfaces two rotary encoder with Raspberry pi and at same time read two sensor values and shown them on tkinter window and now as per project I need to send these values to PC whenever a query command receive from PC .I read from google that if we want two continuous loop then we cab achieve via thread method. But I don't have enough knowledge about threading.
Below I am providing tkinter code as well as TCP/IP code.

```
import pigpio
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import time
from RPi import GPIO
import serial

i="*00T%"
j="*01T%"
s=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0',
                baudrate=9600,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                timeout=1)

class decoder:           # class for decoding rotary encoder 
  def __init__(self, pi, gpioA, gpioB, callback):
      ----------
     ---------------
        ----------------

if __name__ == "__main__":

   rpm=0
   tor=0
   pow=0
   
   pi = pigpio.pi()
   st=1
   pos=0
   def callback(way):  # interrupt event sense on pin no 17,18

      global pos
      global st

      if st ==1:
        pos += way
      if pos >= 9999:
          pos=9999
        if pos <= 0:
          pos=0

        var.set(pos)
       
        print("pos={}".format(pos))
   def rpm_update():
     --------------
     rpm read code
    ---------------
   def tor_update():
     -------------------
     torque read code
     ---------------------

   def pow_update():
    ------------------------
    power Calculation
   --------------------------
  def update():
    --------------------
     root.after(200,update)
   path="/home/pi/logo.png"
   root=tk.Tk()
   img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
   panel=tk.Label(root,image=img)
   panel.pack()
   panel.place(x=195,y=10,height=50,width=80)
   root.title("Dynalec")
   root.geometry("500x600")
 
   {
    body of tkinter screen
   }
   decoder=decoder(pi, 17, 18, callback)
   root.after(200,update)
   root.mainloop()
```

and my server code which is working perfectly in while loop.
I want to merge this two code two achieve desire result perfectly.

```
import socket
import encodings
rpm = 2000
tor = 35
pow = 7.33

HOST = '169.254.29.78' 
PORT = 65432        


def data():
    global rpm, tor, pow
            
    my_sensor = "{},{},{}".format(rpm,tor,pow)
    return my_sensor                            # return data seperated by comma




def my_server():

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        print("Server Started waiting for client to connect ")
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen(5)
        conn, addr = s.accept()

        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:

                data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

                if str(data) == "Data":

                    print("Ok Sending data ")

                    my_data = data()

                    x_encoded_data = my_data.encode('utf-8')

                    conn.sendall(x_encoded_data)

                elif  str(data) == "Quit":
                    print("shutting down server ")
                    break


                if not data:
                    break
                else:
                    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        my_server()
```

Comment: For a start, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, please use interpunction to structure and separate sentences, your question would be more readable if you made separate sentences. However, even worse, you don't really describe what problem you have, you just ask for a solution that seems impossible, because interrupts are a very low-level construct not available at the user level.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I want to write TCP/IP communication on Interrupt as I can't use while loop in this project because of tkinter loop and don't know how to use interrupt service for TCP/IP.